# How to order table results by another rows value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a query to select the `record` column in a table where other rows exist but i want to add an `order by` which orders by another rows value.

```
SELECT 
  record 
FROM 
  record_attributes 
GROUP BY 
  record 
HAVING 
  sum(type = 'lead' AND option_name = 'pupil_cap' AND value > 0) > 0 AND 
  sum(type = 'lead' AND option_name = 'car_type' AND value = 'Manual') > 0 AND 
  sum(type = 'lead' AND option_name = 'instructor_areas_covered' AND value = '26') > 0 AND 
  sum(type = 'lead' AND option_name = 'diary_updates' AND value = '1') > 0
```

How can I order these results by another query in the same table with the following data:

```
ORDER BY record_attributes.value WHERE record_attributes.type = 'lead' AND record_attributes.option_name = 'instructor_rank'
```

And if the row doesn't exist, then use this:

```
ORDER BY record_attributes.value WHERE record_attributes.type = 'lead' AND record_attributes.option_name = 'instructor_start_date'
```

Comment: There has to be a better way to express your sort order than this. Maybe a secondary table that defines the order in which options should appear?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your question is quite confusing.  First, you are not ordering the results of the original table, you are ordering the results of an aggregation function.  Second, your logic suggests that all rows will have the same sort key, which is as good as having no sort key at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood correctly.
But something like this?

```
...
ORDER BY 
MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'lead' AND option_name = 'instructor_rank' THEN value END),
MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'lead' AND option_name = 'instructor_start_date' THEN value END)
```

You can test it [here](https://rextester.com/VPCT61838) on rextester.

Comment: is that after or before the `HAVING` ?

Comment: @charlie ORDER BY comes after GROUP BY and HAVING

Comment: tried that, but getting `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY 
MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'lead' AND option_name = 'instructor_rank' THEN ' at line 12`

Comment: Odd, it works in the test added to the answer. What version of MySql are you using?